# Multiple database in codeigniter project

Tags: database, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I had developed a application in codeigniter. I had a forum like section in my application.
For that I would likes to create a separate database to that controller.

So that I can maintain the site and database very easily.
My question is possible in codeigniter to assign a database to a single controller ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in manix's answer you can pass the settings to the database library constructor.

However what was missed is that you must specify `true` as the second parameter and capture the output in a variable.

```
$DB1 = $this->load->database('group_one', TRUE);
$DB2 = $this->load->database('group_two', TRUE);
```

Failure to do so means you can only work with one database at a time as it replaces the database connection instead of opening a new one!

Note that we are passing in the strings `group_one` and `group_two` these are database setting groups (in your config file you normally only have the `default` group).

You can replace the group name with an array of config options, but it is better to use the groups!

You can then run your queries as

```
//query against first database
$DB1->select(...

//query against second database
$DB2->select(...
```

and you can close one of the connections by using `$DB2->close();` or `$DB1->close();`

More information can be found in the [userguide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can [pass the database connection to the constructor](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html):

```
$config['hostname'] = "localhost";
$config['username'] = "myusername";
$config['password'] = "mypassword";
$config['database'] = "mydatabase";
$config['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$config['dbprefix'] = "";
$config['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$config['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$config['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$config['cachedir'] = "";
$config['char_set'] = "utf8";
$config['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";

$this->load->database($config);
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
copy and paste at database.php

//Another database connection.
$db['database2']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['database2']['username'] = 'root';
$db['database2']['password'] = '';
$db['database2']['database'] = 'dbname2';
$db['database2']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['database2']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['database2']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['database2']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['database2']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['database2']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['database2']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['database2']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['database2']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['database2']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['database2']['stricton'] = FALSE;

//how to use the second database which is configured
$CI= &get_instance();
//set the second parameter to TRUE.
$this->db2 = $CI->load->database('database2', TRUE);
$qry= $this->db2->query("SELECT * FROM db2tables");
var_dump($qry->result());
```

For more details Please refer the below link
http://quandaflow.com/two-databases-connections-codeigniter/